# How to fix a logic bug in numpy python file loading/writing

Tags: python, numpy

I'm recently started to create a roleplay, console based game.

I made this code:

```py
# MAIN GAME LOOP
  while True:
    if MMS == 'A': # already definied
      print('Loading Story mode...')
      print('[LOADING] Importing numpy')
      try:
        import numpy as np
      except ImportError:
        print('Error 01 // Cilent side')
        print('ImportError')
        while True:
          A = 1
      print('[LOADING] Trying load save...')
      try:
        SAVE = np.loadtxt('Savedata.dat')
        MAXLIFE = SAVE[:, 0]  # all of thesse already definied
        LIFE = SAVE[:, 1]
        MAXEN = SAVE[:, 2]
        EN = SAVE[:, 3]
        MAXOX = SAVE[:, 4]
        OX = SAVE[:, 5]
        OPOS = SAVE[:, 6]
        POS = SAVE[:, 7]
        CHAPTER = SAVE[:, 8]
        SAVE.close()
      except:
        sleep(4)
        print('[LOADING] No save file found or incorrect save.')
        print('[LOADING] Creating a new save.')
        MAXLIFE = 150
        LIFE = 110
        MAXEN = 150 
        EN = 150
        MAXOX = 150 
        OX = 85
        OPOS = 10
        POS = 10
        CHAPTER = 1
        np.savetxt('Savedata.dat', [MAXLIFE, LIFE, MAXEN, EN, MAXOX, OX, OPOS, POS, CHAPTER])
```

I except that if there are no saves, it create a new save, with default values. If there are a save, the game loads it.
But, it make this infinite output:

```
[LOADING] No save file found or incorrect save.
[LOADING] Creating a new save.
Loading Story mode...
[LOADING] Importing numpy
[LOADING] Trying load save...
[LOADING] No save file found or incorrect save.
[LOADING] Creating a new save.
Loading Story mode...
...
```

The infinite loop is okay, but it didn't detect its earlier save.

That's in the Savedata.dat

```
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use that bare `except`.  Use the specific type of error that you expect (such as an `io error`),  Otherwise the `except` covers up all kinds of errors, even unexpected ones

Answer (score 1):

As hpaulj said, don't use bare `except`. I rewrited it as:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

(I know, catching just Exceptions is bad too) And it prints me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wakagame.py", line 21, in <module>
    MAXLIFE = SAVE[:, 0]  # all of thesse already definied
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

The problem is that you are trying to pick columns:

`MAXLIFE = SAVE[:, 0]`

not from matrix, but from an average 1D array:

`np.savetxt('Savedata.dat', [MAXLIFE, LIFE, MAXEN, EN, MAXOX, OX, OPOS, POS, CHAPTER])`

You should replace all these lines with lines like this:

`MAXLIFE = SAVE[0]`

*(Also note that SAVE is a numpy array, not a file, so `SAVE.close()` will return an error. You should remove this line)*